# The package org.openqa.selenium is accessible from more than one module: htmlunit.driver, phantomjsdriver, selenium, selenium.server.standalone

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I am learning Selenium, I have downloaded all required jar files and started eclipse but when i am trying to use webdriver, I am getting this error:

> error-The package org.openqa.selenium is accessible from more than one
>   module: htmlunit.driver, phantomjsdriver, selenium,
>   selenium.server.standalone

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

Keep reference to only one module.
Remove the rest and it will work.
Repeat until there is no error message.