# The package org.openqa.selenium is accessible from more than one module: net.bytebuddy, phantomjsdriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, phantomjs

I am working with `Selenium Web Driver` and `PhantomJSDriver 2.1.1` for extract data from a page. As shown in screenshot below, I found a problem with `import WebDriver`**:**
"`The package org.openqa.selenium is accessible from more than one module: net.bytebuddy, phantomjsdriver`".
[Screenshot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcI9x.jpg)
I searched through the net and forums, and found some topics such as [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834695/the-package-org-openqa-selenium-is-accessible-from-more-than-one-module) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47125039/the-package-org-openqa-selenium-is-accessible-from-more-than-one-module-htmluni) but the issue has not yet been solved. How can I resolve it? please help me. Sorry for my bad English writing!